# Undefined Reference to deck::array1 in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, static-methods, static-variables

I have header file in which I have static function which are public and i have a private static array. In my c++ file file i am calling my array from one of this static function and getting error "UNDEFINED REFERENCE TO abc::ARRAY". why I am getting this error?
When I remove static from array and function it works properly. But I need to make them static to use in another c++ file

[See my code for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3TqO.jpg)

Comment: You know code is just text, and you can paste it here, right? Why do we have to look at a picture of it?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't define the array in a .cpp file:

```
std::array<int, 52> deck::deckArray;
```

Comment: @SilentDownvoters: any reason?

Comment: Yea it works . Many thanks.